Self-adjoint matrices which are positive definite.
This is an important application of "Spectrum theorem for self-adjoint operator" in my book. I'm lacking an theoretical view of linear algebra. So, this causes me trouble. Firstly, the spectrum theorem in my book:

And then, the author claims these two results, which is deemed to be "direct application of Spectrum theorem".

If $A$ is self-adjoint and also positive definite, then all of its eigenvalues are positive. In particular, $detA \geq 0$ and $tr A \geq 0$.
If $A$ is self-adjoint and indefinite, then it has at least one positive and one negative eigenvalues.

How are these things true using the theorem above?

For 1) you don't need the theorem. It follows easily from definitions.

Supposedly, a self-adjoint linear operator $A$ is called positive definite if $\langle Ax,x\rangle>0$ for all nonzero vectors $x$. Positive semidefiinite, negative definite/semidefinite and indefinite operators are also defined by considering the sign of $\langle Ax,x\rangle$ for an arbitrary nonzero vector $x$.
So, if $A$ is positive definite, then $R(x)>0$ for all $x\ne0$. Therefore, by the stated theorem, $\min_j\lambda_j=\min_{x\ne0}R(x)>0$. In turn, all $\lambda_j$s are positive, $\det A=\prod_j\lambda_j>0$ and $\operatorname{tr}(A)=\sum_j\lambda_j>0$.
If $A$ is indefinite, then $\langle Ax,x\rangle$ is positive for some $x$ and negative for some other $x$. That is, $R(x)$ is positive for some $x$ and negative for some other $x$. Therefore, by the stated theorem,
$$
\max_j\lambda_j=\max_{x\ne0}R(x)>0>\min_{x\ne0}R(x)=\min_j\lambda_j,
$$
meaning that the greatest eigenvalue of $A$ is positive and the least eigenvalue of $A$ is negative.

But wait. This is not quite right. The $\lambda_i$ in the theorem are from the choice of $(a_1, a_2, ..., a_n)$. It is from a "there exists" statement. We do not have a general conclusion on any $\lambda_i$ of $A$, right? Am I missing something?

@DuckGia The spectrum of a matrix is unique. Since the $a_i$s form an eigenbasis, the $\lambda_i$s already constitute the complete spectrum of $A$.

Can you give me some reference on this? I have almost zero experience with linear algebra at the moment. Some theorem that supports your above point would do. Thank you :D

@DuckGia I don’t know any book that answers particularly your doubt, but in general, a scalar $\lambda$ is called an eigenvalue of $A$ if $Ax=\lambda x$ for some nonzero vector $x$. Since this equation can be rewritten as $(\lambda I-A)x=0$, $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ only if $\lambda I-A$ is singular, i.e., only if it is a root of the polynomial equation $\det(xI-A)=0$. This leads us to define the spectrum of $A$ as the unique set of roots of $\det(xI-A)=0$. ...

...Now, if $A$ has an eigenbasis ${a_1,\ldots,a_n}$ such that $Aa_i=\lambda_ia_i$, then $AP=P\Lambda$ where $P$ is the matrix $\pmatrix{a_1&\cdots&a_n}$ and $\Lambda=\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)$. Therefore $A=P\Lambda P^{-1}$ and $\det(xI-A)=\det(xI-P\Lambda P^{-1})=\det\big(P(xI-\Lambda)P^{-1}\big)=\det(xI-\Lambda)=\prod_i(x-\lambda_i)$. Therefore ${\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n}$ is the spectrum of $A$.

Why is $det(xI−PΛP^{-1})=det(P(xI−Λ)P^{-1})$?

@DuckGia Because $P(xI)P^{-1}=xI$
